# Magento2 How To Add Delete confirmation Popup on Magento default Import functionality for delete behaviour

Tags: magento2, import

I have Added one custom entity in default Magento import. On delete behaviour action, need to display the delete confirmation popup with message (it will delete all record) on import button click. Can anyone please guide me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Add this below code in your file and see it it works

```
<script>
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
        jQuery('.action-delete').click(function(e)
    {
        if(confirm('Do you want to remove all records?'))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false; 
        }

    });
 });
</script>
```